# Group Action of $SO(3)$ on unit sphere

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology, geometric-group-theory

We know that $SO(3)$ acts transitively on $S^2$. That is, given any two points $p_1,p_2\in S^2$, one can find an element in $SO(3)$ mapping $p_1$ to $p_2$. My question is, given two sets of points $(a_1,a_2)$ and $(b_1,b_2)$ on $S^2$ such that the induced distance on sphere are the same, can one necessarily find an element in $SO(3)$ mapping one set to the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes; this is just elementary geometry.  We may first choose a rotation sending $a_1$ to $b_1$, and so may assume $a_1=b_1$.  Then we can choose a rotation about the diameter of the sphere through $a_1$ that maps $a_2$ to $b_2$.  (Explicitly, rotate by the angle between the geodesic from $a_1$ to $a_2$ and the geodesic from $a_1$ to $b_2$.)

Comment: I'm wondering what is the largest number of points that we can perform this?

Comment: I think my actual question is, when can we uniquely determine an element in $SO(3)$ by specifying the number of points that we match. More generally, how about $SO(n)$, $SU(n)$? Thanks a lot!

Comment: An element of $SO(n)$ (or $SU(n)$) is uniquely determined by where it sends any collection of $n-1$ linearly independent vectors, since if you take an $n$th vector orthogonal to those $n-1$ its image is uniquely determined by needing to remain orthogonal to them and produce a determinant of $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Take $a_3 = a_1 \times a_2$ and $b_3 = b_1 \times b_2$. Define the map $T: \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^3$ by the formula $T(a_i) = b_i$. This map is a oriented isometry of $\mathbb R^3$ and therefore belongs to $SO(3)$.